# Mathematica 8 on Windows 98

Tags: windows

This is a pretty simple question. Does Mathematica 8 work on Windows 98? I would really appreciate a response.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess the answer is NO since MMA8 was released around 2011.

Comment: MMA 8 system requirements can be found here - http://support.wolfram.com/kb/10843?lang=en

Comment: @Edmund Go ahead an post your comment as an answer and catch some reputation.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/190205/mathematica-on-windows-98/190207#190207 (I would nearly go so far as to call it a duplicate)

Answer (score 4):

You can have a try yourself! Simply go to the installation directory, select Mathematica.exe, right click, choose settings, and choose compatibility settings, and change the version to win98. Now try to open the program. It won't, so the answer is no.

Answer (score 2):

MMA 8 system requirements can be found here [What are Mathematica 8 system requirements?](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/10843?lang=en) for all operating systems.

The earliest version listed for Windows is Windows XP SP2, so may be out of luck for Win 98.

Comment: No, it runs fine on windows XP as well. Your answer is  not really correct.

Comment: @t-smart You can't get any more authoritative then the creators of the software.  In any case, I've changed it to "may be out of luck" for the adventurous.

Comment: The earliest listed on that page is WinXP SP2 (Win 7 is the first on the list, but not the earliest).